# Translation from math to english – algorithm for generation of graphs with known χ

Tags: graph-theory

As [I haven’t been able to find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38154012/2948889) such an algorithm implemented I’d like to implement the one from the section 6 of [Leighton’s paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.6028/jres.084.024)¹ myself. I however am not familiar with a notation used in the description of the algorithm.

Therefore I would appreciate if someone familiar with this syntax could confirm whether line 2 has the meaning of $\mathrm{gcd}(n,m)$ and if → in number 4 implies implication.

1. $m ≫ n$,
2. $(n,m)=k$,
3. $(c,m)=1$,
4. $p∣m → p∣(a-1)$ for all primes $p$, and
5. $4∣m → 4∣(a-1)$.

---

¹ Leighton, F. T. (1979). A graph coloring algorithm for large scheduling problems. In *Journal of Research of the National Bureau of Standards* (pp. 489-506). http://doi.org/10.6028/jres.084.024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and yes.  Good job.

You might get more ideas from Blitzstein and Diaconis, "[A Sequential Importance Sampling Algorithm for Generating Random Graphs with Prescribed Degrees](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~blitz/BlitzsteinDiaconisGraphAlgorithm.pdf)", 2006.  They review several previous algorithms that control degree (not chromaticity) and describe their own in detail.  More can be found in Moseman's "[Improving the Computational Efficiency of the Blitzstein-Diaconis Algorithm for Generating Random Graphs of Prescribed Degree](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ir/2015/NIST.IR.8066.pdf)", 2015.  Again, these aren't exact matches for your desired algorithm, but some of the ideas will transfer.